# Code works in CodeBlocks, but gives errors when compiling in linux

Tags: c++, linux

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "cootie.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Time to create a Cootie!" << endl;
    cootie c;
    c.setName(name);
    cout << "Add body parts." << endl;
    cout << "1) Body" << endl << "2) Head" << endl << "3) Legs" << endl << "4) Wings" << endl << "5) Antennas" << endl << "6) Eyes" << endl;
    cout << "Input 7 to print.";
    while (roll != 7)
    {
        cin >> roll;
        if (roll == 1)
        {
            c.setBody(numBody);
        }
        if (roll == 2)
        {
            c.setHead(numHead);
        }
        if (roll == 3)
        {
            c.setLeg(numLeg);
        }
        if (roll == 4)
        {
            c.setWing(numWing);
        }
        if (roll == 5)
        {
            c.setAntenna(numAntenna);
        }
        if (roll == 6)
        {
            c.setEye(numEye);
        }
        if (roll == 7)
        {
            c.print();
        }
    }
}
```

cootie.h

```
#ifndef COOTIE_H
#define COOTIE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class cootie
{
    public:
        cootie();
        int numLeg, numHead, numEye, numWing, numBody, numAntenna, roll;
        string name = "Undefined";
        int setName(string& name);
        int setLeg(int& numLeg);
        int setHead(int& numHead);
        int setEye(int& numEye);
        int setWing(int& numWing);
        int setBody(int& numBody);
        int setAntenna(int& numAntenna);
        void print(string name, int numLeg, int numHead, int numEye, int numWing, int numBody, int numAntenna);
};

#endif // COOTIE_H
```

cootie.cpp

```
#include "cootie.h"


cootie::cootie()
{
    numLeg;
    numHead;
    numEye;
    numWing;
    numBody;
    numAntenna;
    roll;
    name = "Undefined";
}

int cootie::setName(string& name)
{
    cout << "Name your Cootie!" << endl;
    getline(cin, name);
}
int cootie::setBody(int& numBody)
{
    numBody++;
}
int cootie::setHead(int& numHead)
{
    numHead++;
}
int cootie::setWing(int& numWing)
{
    numWing++;
}
int cootie::setLeg(int& numLeg)
{
    numLeg++;
}
int cootie::setEye(int& numEye)
{
    numEye++;
}
int cootie::setAntenna(int& numAntenna)
{
    numAntenna++;
}
void cootie::print(string name, int numLeg, int numHead, int numEye, int numWing, int numBody, int numAntenna)
{
    cout << "Cootie called " << name << endl;
    cout << numLeg << " Leg(s)" << endl;
    cout << numHead << " Head(s)" << endl;
    cout << numEye << " Eye(s)" << endl;
    cout << numWing << " Wings(s)" << endl;
    cout << numBody << " Body(s)" << endl;
    cout << numAntenna << " Antenna(s)" << endl;
}
```

I'm attempting to compile these files in linux, but i can't get the cootie.cpp to compile into source code. I tried using "g++ -c cootie.cpp" but i ended up getting errors.

> cootie.h:11:22: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member 'numLeg'
>   cootie.h:11:22: error: making 'numLeg' static
>   cootie.h:11:22: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'numLeg'

I tried compiling with the std=c++11 flag, but i got cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11" as an error, so i tried std=c++0x but that gave me the same errors i had initially.

Modified the code, but now i receive this error when i compile with the std=c++0x flag

/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/4.5.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/glibc-tmp-6341ca4bac93b935314b1241c89966aa/glibc-2.13/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/elf/start.S:109: undefined reference to`main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm pretty new to linux, so i'm not really sure whats causing the issue.

Comment: Did you turn on C++11?

Comment: You need to switch on C++11 support. Use the `std=c++11` flag.

Comment: How exactly do i use that flag?

Comment: I tried compiling with the `std=c++11` flag, but i got **cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"** as an error, so i tried `std=c++0x` but that gave me the same errors i had initially

Comment: You really, *really* need to study the basics more. There's almost nothing that's *correct* in your code except syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize instance variables (e.g. `numLeg`) in the class definition in < C++11x. You have to initialize them in the constructor, e.g. like this:

```
cootie::cootie()
{
  numLeg = 0;
  numHead = 0;
  numEye = 0;
  numWing = 0;
  numBody = 0;
  numAntenna = 0;
  roll = 0;
}
```

Just remove the `= 0` in your header file before every instance variable.

Comment: You *can*, but only *since* C++0x (which is now C++11).

Comment: Just tried that, but when i attempted to compile it again it gave this `/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/4.5.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/glibc-tmp-6341ca4bac93b935314b1241c89966aa/glibc-2.13/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/elf/start.S:109: undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @ZacharyMcCloud, You're presumably only compiling and linking your implementation file instead of it and the main file. That's a completely different problem from the question.

Comment: You have to include `main.cpp` in your commands to compile and link. `cootie.cpp` is not a whole program.

Comment: I thought i was just trying to compile the cootie.cpp into source code, and then compile that and main.cpp together? Literally brand new to this, sorry for stupid questions.

Comment: Okay, i tried compiling them together like you said and it works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
int numLeg = 0, numHead = 0, numEye = 0, numWing = 0, numBody = 0, numAntenna = 0, roll = 0;
```

You need to drop the `= 0`'s, end intitialize them in the constructor. I.o.w:

```
class cootie
{
public:
    int numLeg, numHead, numEye, numWing, numBody, numAntenna, roll;

    cootie::cootie()
    : numLeg(0)
    , numHead(0)
    , ...
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: No, the default is default-initialized, which means uninitialized for `int`.